# Confused about how Rotation works in vulkan

Tags: c++, game-engine, vulkan, glm-math

I set up a Vulkan Pipeline using Branden Gela's tutorials and started putting together my own system using it. I derived a class from his gameobject class.

The gameobject has some transform matrices like this.

```
glm::mat4 TransformComponent::mat4()
    {
        {
            const float c3 = glm::cos(rotation.z);
            const float s3 = glm::sin(rotation.z);
            const float c2 = glm::cos(rotation.x);
            const float s2 = glm::sin(rotation.x);
            const float c1 = glm::cos(rotation.y);
            const float s1 = glm::sin(rotation.y);
            return glm::mat4{
                {
                    scale.x * (c1 * c3 + s1 * s2 * s3),
                    scale.x * (c2 * s3),
                    scale.x * (c1 * s2 * s3 - c3 * s1),
                    0.0f,
                },
                {
                    scale.y * (c3 * s1 * s2 - c1 * s3),
                    scale.y * (c2 * c3),
                    scale.y * (c1 * c3 * s2 + s1 * s3),
                    0.0f,
                },
                {
                    scale.z * (c2 * s1),
                    scale.z * (-s2),
                    scale.z * (c1 * c2),
                    0.0f,
                },
                {translation.x, translation.y, translation.z, 1.0f} };
        }
    }
    glm::mat3 TransformComponent::normalMatrix()
    {
            const float c3 = glm::cos(rotation.z);
            const float s3 = glm::sin(rotation.z);
            const float c2 = glm::cos(rotation.x);
            const float s2 = glm::sin(rotation.x);
            const float c1 = glm::cos(rotation.y);
            const float s1 = glm::sin(rotation.y);
            const glm::vec3 invScale = 1.0f/scale;
            return glm::mat3{
                {
                    invScale.x * (c1 * c3 + s1 * s2 * s3),
                    invScale.x * (c2 * s3),
                    invScale.x * (c1 * s2 * s3 - c3 * s1),
                },
                {
                    invScale.y * (c3 * s1 * s2 - c1 * s3),
                    invScale.y * (c2 * c3),
                    invScale.y * (c1 * c3 * s2 + s1 * s3),
                },
                {
                    invScale.z * (c2 * s1),
                    invScale.z * (-s2),
                    invScale.z * (c1 * c2),
                },
            };
    }
```

Now I want to set up a quad and have it face the camera. But the problem is I can't seem to get it to properly face the camera AT ALL!

Right now my code sets it up like this:

```
 player.transform.rotation = { 190.f,0.f,0.f };
```

And this is the result(SIDE VIEW):
Note: My player IS derived from gameobject

[image]

It's not completely 180. Nor 190 imo.
I don't know if it's a something to do with my camera, but I am NOT setting any default rotations for the camera. Does this have to do with the way Vulkan handles Rotation or am I missing something?

Comment: Vulkan itself does not do anything with rotations, those are handled by your own code (e.g.: a transformation matrix)

Comment: @UnholySheep well what's wrong with my matrix?

Comment: Impossible to tell, since I have no context what `player.transform.rotation` is used for or how any data gets prepared or passed to the shaders, etc. There is simply too much missing information (and generally this is something you'll have to debug in the application itself)

Comment: The angles are in radians, not degrees.

Comment: @molbdnilo YES! THAT WAS IT! THAT FIXED IT!